# The heading should be editable with an edit icon near it

Tags: javascript, ajax

The heading should be editable with an edit icon near it, and while clicking edit icon input box should appear and what i type should replace the heading...

Comment: This is not a coding service

Comment: Dear Jack, _SO_ is not a free coding service.. Do add your efforts in your question so that contributors can help you solve your problem..

Comment: Great. You have a clear idea about what you want to do. Just try to do it now. And if you face any issue, only then ask questions here and also add the code too for others.

Comment: function changeInputText() {
    if($("#input").val() === "Heading") {
      $("h6").text("Home");
    } else {
      $("label").text("NewHome");
    };
  };